# NSTimer getting zombie

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nszombie

I have created a NSTimer in my application which gets fired after every 1 min interval. my problem is when I put the application in background and after some time say 5 min, i bring that in foreground, the timer object gets zombied.

any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps invalidate the timer when the application enters the background then start it again when the application enters the foreground.

Like so:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(TimerFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have some task to do, so i cant stop the timer

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` objects are retained when scheduled. Your timer might be invalidated for some reason and by thus, released.

Comment: I m invalidating timer only when i m coming back to foreground. I confirmed by logs. The object is getting zombied when I comes in foreground and when I calls [myTimer invalidate]; it gets crash.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in -[NSTimer invalidate] to see if anybody else is invalidating your timer. A scheduled timer is retained properly. Except you are overreleasing it anywhere else. Uses Instrument's Object Allocations tool to find where the timer is released.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Because of one detach thread the timer was invalidated for two times, Currently added one bool in my code and so far its working.